# Input impedance of audio amplifier, unclear from datasheet

Tags: amplifier, dc, impedance

I have a AN7190NK audio power IC. It is a amplifier for the car radio.
I want to know it's input impedance. 
In [datasheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheetpdf/view/13447/PANASONIC/AN7190NK.html) it states that:

Input impedance ZI VIN = ± 0.3 VDC  28 kOhm

I don't really understand what Vin = ± 0.3 VDC mean. These are conditions at which impedance was measured. What does that mean?
The VDC is not mentioned in datasheet after that.

Comment: Link to datasheet, please, in the question (not in the comments).

Comment: It means that the input voltage was within 0.3V of the ground reference.

Comment: http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/13447/PANASONIC/AN7190NK.html

Comment: Sigh! In the question. Not in the comments. That way anyone trying to answer your question has all the relevant information in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Above ±0.3 V the input protection circuit will shunt the signal and drop the impedance.

**Long answer**

The [AN7190 datasheet](http://www.quartz1.com/price/PIC/410N0150000.pdf) doesn't show the internal circuit for the chip but we can deduce a few things from the application circuit example.

[image]

*Figure 1. Application example from datasheet page 5.*

- The amplifier is designed for in-car entertainment systems. That means single-ended 12 V supply will be used.
- Traditionally in single-ended supplied amplifiers the input is biased to half supply and a decoupling capacitor is used on the input. In the application note we can see that there is no decoupling capacitor and the input voltage can swing positive and negative with respect to ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0DXoI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Input protection circuit guess.*

- Most likely there is some input protection (like back to back diodes between the input and ground) to limit the maximum input signal. This would limit the DC thump on power-up caused by the previous stage equipment output if, for example, it *is* biased to half-supply and used a decoupling capacitor on its output. Instead of getting a 6 V thump the protection will probably clamp it at about 0.6 V. This will protect your ears and your equipment. The 47 k\$\Omega\$ input resistors give a discharge path to any external decoupling capacitors.
- The imput impedance is specified at 28 k\$\Omega\$ for signals in the range ±0.3 V. Outside that the impedance will fall as the protection shunts the current.
- The elimination of the input decoupling capacitors will avoid low-frequency roll-off and so give improved bass. The bridge mode output similarly avoids decoupling capacitors to further improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

You measure the input impedance of an amplifier by plugging a voltage source at it's input and, knowing the internal resistance of the source you can deduce the input impedance by a simple voltage divider model :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY9O9P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The +/- 0.3 V are the imprecision of Vs.

More on the subject : http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/input-impedance-of-an-amplifier.html

Comment: "_The +/- 0.3 V are the imprecision of Vs._" If that was the case then V\$_S\$ would have been stated. e.g., 10 V ±0.3 V. I suspect that it's because of an input protection device. See my answer.